# Getting linker error while Gmail Integration

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to integrate Gmail for login .

I have followed every step of there documentation but getting the following linker errors.

**Note:-** I am using manual SDK rather than Cocoa Pods.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/harpreet/Documents/FacebookSDK'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      l010 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      l059 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: having same issue..

Comment: Same issue don't know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766179/getting-clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invo/38261390#38261390

Answer (score 12):

Make sure to also add:

- `GoogleUtilities.framework`
- `GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework`
- `GoogleAuthUtilities.framework`
- `GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework`
- `GoogleAppUtilities.framework`

[image: All required]

And the ones listed in the official documentation:

- `AddressBook.framework`
- `SafariServices.framework`
- `SystemConfiguration.framework`

If you use the Google icon, import:

- `GoogleSignIn.bundle`

Find the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/)

Comment: I just used Google Plus for sign in rather than Gmail login.

Comment: All these dependencies should be documented on the official docs https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/

Comment: For those curious about how to get these frameworks - go to https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn and look at the 'Depends on' section. For each of these go and 'See Podspec' where you will find the download under "Source" eg: "http": "https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/bea34d9a0098d2a2-GoogleAppUtilities-1.1.1.tar.gz"
Mind that `GoogleAuthUtilities` depends on `GoogleSymbolUtilities`

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**add all this from sdk(google_signin_sdk_4_0_0) to your project**

GoogleAppUtilities.framework

GoogleAuthUtilities.framework

GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework

GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework

GoogleUtilities.framework

GoogleSignIn.framework

GoogleSignIn.bundle

**Go to**

**build Phases     -> link binary with Libraries**

**add this framework**

SafariServices.framework

AddressBook.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

**also add this two files**

libc++.tbd

libz.tbd

Comment: I have the same issue by following these steps could you please explain in detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also added:

```
GoogleAuthUtilities.framework
GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework
GoogleAppUtilities.framework
GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework
SafariServices.framework
```

Also, if you need too, add

```
GoogleSignIn.bundle
```

to your bundle resource.

This works for me